# Mixture of Poissons for positive and negative integers

Tags: poisson-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'm trying to design a generative model for a random variable $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The model would work as follows. First draw $b\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$. If $b=1$, draw $k\sim\text{Poisson}(c)$. Otherwise, draw $j\sim\text{Poisson}(d)$ and let $k=-j$.

In this way, the Poisson distribution parameterized by $c$ would generate non-negative values of $k$ and the Poisson distribution parameterized by $d$ would generate non-positive values of $k$. A Bernoulli random variable would tell you which distribution to draw from.

I want to confirm the likelihood function for the variable $k$ drawn from this model given values of $p$, $c$, and $d$. What I came up with was:

$Pr(k;p,c,d)=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{c^ke^{-c}}{k!} & k>0 \\
      \frac{d^{-k}e^{-d}}{(-k)!} & k<0 \\
      pe^{-c}+(1-p)e^{-d} & k = 0
\end{cases}$

**Is this the correct likelihood for such a model?** I'm having issues learning the parameters of this function given a set of data for which this model seems reasonable and want to confirm my likelihood is correct.

Comment: It's not a correct pmf. It would sum to more than 1.

Comment: if $\textrm{truncpois}(k,c)$ is the probability of drawing $k$ from a *zero-truncated* Poisson, then I think the likelihood for $k>0$ is $p \cdot \textrm{truncpois}(k,c)$ and so on ...

Comment: That's pretty much a complete answer to the question, you could consider posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the Bernoulli probability from the cases where $k \neq 0$.  Your sampling distribution should be:

$$p(k|p,c,d) = \begin{cases}
(1-p) \cdot d^{-k} e^{-d} / |k|! & & & \text{for } k<0, \\[6pt]
p e^{-c} + (1-p) e^{-d} & & & \text{for } k=0, \\[6pt]
p \cdot c^{k} e^{-c} / |k|! & & & \text{for } k>0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

Comment: My mistake was thinking we could condition on the fact that, for example, $k < 0$, making it unnecessary to think about $p$.